# C++ string length in bytes

Tags: c++, string

```
string str; str="hello"; str.length(); sizeof(str);
```

I see that str.length returns the length in bytes why sizeof(str) doesn't return the same?

Is there alternative in c++ to a c command which is strlen(str)? What is the alternative of this coomand in c++?

When I use winsock in the send function I return the length in bytes. What should I use?
str.length? Or sizeof(str)? Pr something else? Because I see they produce different results.

Comment: "Is there alternative in c++ to a c command which is strlen(str)?" Yes, and you're using it. `.length`.

Comment: string.length() returns the number of characters in the string, sizeof(str) returns the number of bytes the string object occupies in memory.

Comment: `strlen()` is not a command, nor is `sizeof`. The former is a function, the latter is an operator.

Answer (score 4):

sizeof returns the size of the data structure, not the size of the data in contains.

length() returns the length of the string that str contains, and is the function you want

It might seem confusing because sizeof(char[30]) is 30, but that is because the size of the data structure is 30, and will remain 30 no matter what you put in it

The string is actually an extremely complicated structure, but suppose it was a simple class with a pointer and a length

```
class string
{
    char *data;
    int length;
};
```

then sizeof(string) would return:

The size of a char * pointer, possibly but not necessarily 4

**plus** the size of an int, possibly but not necessarily 4

So you might get a value of 8. What the value of data or length is has no effect on the size of the structure.

Comment: ... *plus* the size of the padding, possibly but not necessarily zero.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof()` is not really meant to be used on a string class. The string class doesn't store ONLY the string data; there would be no difference between its data and a C-style string; it has other stuff in it as well, which throws off sizeof(). To get the actual length of the characters in the string, use `str.length()`.
Don't use the C strlen() on a C++ string object. Don't use sizeof() either. Use `.length().`

Comment: sizeof is not taking any notice of the contents of the string, only of the size of the data structure

Comment: As far as `sizeof()` is concerned, most string classes don't store the string data at all. Most or all of it will usually be on the heap, which `sizeof()` doesn't look at.

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` in C++ is instantiated as a pointer to a string object, since a string may have varying length. What `sizeof()` is returning is the size of the pointer to the string object (which on a 32 bit machine will probably be `4`)

Comment: You must be a java or c# programmer. In c++, string str; creates an actual string object on the stack, no pointers involved

Comment: In VS2008 a 32 bit release mode string has a size of 28

Answer (score 0):

Operator `sizeof()` returns size of given type or object in bytes. 'Type version' is quite simple to understand, bu with 'Object version' you need to rember one thing:

> `sizeof()` looks only on type definition and deduces total size from size and number of its members (in general, polymorphic and multiple inherited types may have additional 'hidden' members).

In other words, let's assume we have:

```
struct A
{
  int* p1;
  char* p2;
};
```

As you can probably suspect, `sizeof(A)` will return 8 (as pointer is 4-byte type on most 32-bit systems). But, when you do something like this:

```
A a_1;
a_1.p1 = new int[64];
```

`sizeof(a_1)` will still return 8. That's because memory allocated by new and pointed by A's member, does not 'belong' to this object.

And that is why `sizeof(str)` and `str.length()` give different results. `std::string` allocates memory for chars on the heap (dynamically, via `malloc()`), so it doesn't change string's size.

So, if you want to send string via network, proper size is `str.len()` and data pointer can be retrieved by calling `str.c_str()`.

I didn't understant part with "`strlen(str)` equivalent". In C++ there is also `strlen()` function, with the same prototype, working exactly in the same way. It simply requires `const char*`, so you cannot use it for `std::string` (but you can do `strlen(str.c_str())`, as `std::string`'s internal string is guaranteed to be null-terminated). For `std::string` use `.length()` as you already did.